# How to create an ImpEx for Hybris promotion rule?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have created a promotion rule in Backoffice and its working fine for the storefront.How to import it via ImpEx as the conditions and actions and uuid present there are generated dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, what i did is :

## Configure Your condition via Impex

Create a condition :

```
$lang = en
INSERT_UPDATE RuleConditionDefinition; id[unique=true]; name; priority; allowsChildren; translatorId; translatorParameters; categories(id)
;y_condition_id; Condition Name; 1100; false; YourCustomConditionTranslator; ; cart;
```

Create Condition parameters ( here is an example of a condition parameter) :

```
INSERT_UPDATE RuleConditionDefinitionParameter;definition(id)[unique=true];id[unique=true];name[lang = $lang];priority;type;value;required[default=true];validators;filters;defaultEditor
;y_condition_id;operator;Operator;1300;Enum(de.hybris.platform.ruledefinitions.AmountOperator);"""GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL""";;;
```

Then Map your condition to Promotion RuleType :

```
INSERT_UPDATE RuleConditionDefinitionRuleTypeMapping;definition(id)[unique=true];ruleType(code)[default=PromotionSourceRule][unique=true]
;y_condition_id;
```

## Configure your action

Create Action definition :

```
INSERT_UPDATE RuleActionDefinition;id[unique=true];name[lang = $lang];priority;;translatorId;translatorParameters;categories(id)
;y_action_Id;Action Name;1000;;YourActionTranslator;actionId->YourAction;product_discounts
```

Create your Action parameters :

```
INSERT_UPDATE RuleActionDefinitionParameter;definition(id)[unique=true];id[unique=true];name[lang=$lang];priority;type;value;required[default=true];validators;filters
;y_action_Id;your_param_id;Your parameter name ;1000;java.lang.Integer;1;;YourParameterValidator;
```

Map your Action to Promotion ruleType :

```
INSERT_UPDATE RuleActionDefinitionRuleTypeMapping;definition(id)[unique=true];ruleType(code)[default=PromotionSourceRule][unique=true]
;y_action_Id;
```

## Create Promotion template

First i created My promotion template using ImpEx without setting any parameters except name :

```
INSERT_UPDATE PromotionSourceRuleTemplate;code[unique=true];name[lang=$lang];
;promotion_template_id; Template name;;
```

Then I have modified the template from backoffice, by Adding my condition and my action to the promotion template *Conditions & Actions* tab ( Add them by a Drag and drop), then save your template.

Then check the Administration Tab, you will find a **Condition** field containing a json ( this json is containing the definition of your conditions with the generated `uuid` you asked about in your question ) , similarly for actions, **Actions** field containing a json definiton of Promotion template actions.

So Here you are able to create your promotion template using Impex :

```
INSERT_UPDATE PromotionSourceRuleTemplate;code[unique=true];maxAllowedRuns;ruleGroup(code);conditions;actions
;promotion_template_id;1;productPromotionRuleGroup;[{your conditions json here}];[{ your action json here}]
```

Hope this will Help you

Comment: Was this helpful ? any feedback will be very appreciated

Comment: I think this could be useful only if you want to create a new template, not to create a new promotion :(